# SQL: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UA_TRIGGER_PAGAMENTO, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'

Tags: sql-server, triggers, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a simple trigger, and used the template given from SQL Server Management Studio. I've already made an extensive search and couldn't find a solution. I apologize for some text being in Portuguese, but the database it's in the same language.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UA_TRIGGER_PAGAMENTO
ON dbo.PagamentoSet
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @vEstado VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @vIdSocio INT;
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SET @vEstado = (SELECT Estado FROM inserted);
    SET @vIdSocio = (SELECT Socio_Id FROM inserted);

    IF (@vEstado = 'PAGO') THEN
        UPDATE SocioSet
        SET Atualizado = 'True'
        WHERE Id = @vIdSocio;   
    END IF;
END
GO
```

When I try to run it, I get the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UA_TRIGGER_PAGAMENTO, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UA_TRIGGER_PAGAMENTO, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

I've already tried declaring the variables inside de BEGIN - END. Tried not putting semicolon. And nothing.

Thank you

Comment: [IF ... ELSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182717.aspx) (note, no `THEN` keyword). [BEGIN ... END](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190487.aspx) (Note, not `END IF`). And your trigger is broken - `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT Estado FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Triggers in sql server are fired per statement, not per row. This means that your inserted table might contain multiple values. Your current trigger will raise an error (Subquery returned more then one value) in such cases.

Here is the correct way to write your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UA_TRIGGER_PAGAMENTO
ON dbo.PagamentoSet
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

        UPDATE t 
        Set Atualizado = 'True'
        FROM SocioSet t 
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.Id = i.Socio_Id
        WHERE t.Estado = 'PAGO';

END
GO
```

Also, for future reference, the correct way to write if...else conditions in sql is

```
IF condition
BEGIN
    -- statements
END
[ELSE
BEGIN
   -- statements
END]
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution. Remove 'THEN' and 'END IF'.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx